# How to call a JS function when a textbox text property changes?

Tags: javascript

I would like to catch the change of a textbox value in JavaScript.
Not sure if there is such an event?

And I would like to call my own function when this change happens and pass the new updated text value to my function....

e.g. when user interacts on the website and programatically a textbox value changes, I would like to catch this and read the value and send it to my function, lets assume the function is called **updatedText('string value here')** and would take a string.

Edit:

I tried the following code, which works fine to read a textbox value (the textbox is on a form element):

```
var form = document.forms['freqform'];
var freq_input = form.elements[3];
var str = freq_input.value;
alert(str);
```

This works fine and an alert pops up showing the current value of this textbox.

Now I have added the following code that you recommended in the first link:

```
freq_input.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    alert('Function has fired');
});
```

But the alert box does not fire, when the textbox value was changed by other javascript running on the site. (I am testing it as a snippet in Chrome DevTools)

If I change/shorten it to:

```
freq_input.addEventListener('input', alert('Function has fired'));
```

It works, but fires immediately after execution and only once....afterwards it does not fire again when input value changes (I also tried the change event with same effect).

Thanks for your help, I am still abit noobish on JS (normally doing vb.net)

Comment: Adding a way to do it in vanilla JS too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946235/pure-javascript-listen-to-input-value-change

Comment: Studying some basic form control tutorials would help

Comment: use on change: `<textarea onchange="updatedText(this.value)"></textarea>`