# How to get WKWebview height while typing in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, height, wkwebview

I have a simple WKWebview.

At first, I am able to get its height once the webview is loaded.

```
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight;") { (result, error) in
            if error == nil, let value = result {
                if let height = value as? Int {
                    // found the webview's height here.
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

But after this, I need to get the webview's height **while typing**. How to achieve this in iOS, swift?

Comment: While typing where?? JS or Swift side?

Comment: It is an editable wkwebview where we can type. So, while typing **in wkwebview**.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a timer, just add an event listener into your input in wkwebview ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946235/pure-javascript-listen-to-input-value-change) how to do this, similar to `textViewDidChange` on iOS) and invoke there:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight;") { (result, error) in
            if error == nil, let value = result {
                if let height = value as? Int {
                    // found the webview's height here.
                }
            }
        }
```