Retrieving Data from a Table
I have a table with ID 'myTable' and an input Box ID 'Search'. Normally I type some text into input Text box and retrieve relevant data from the table. The code is working fine, the moment i type any value in input text box, the code responds and gives the desired result without even hitting the Enter Key. But when I select any desired value from the TD (which is normally a word from  a sentence), copy the same value and paste it into text box, the code does not respond until and unless the input box is: autofocused by clicking into it; and then entering the Enter/Return Key. Apart from typing of desired value from a sentence of td (as i am presently doing), I wish to  paste  it into input box with a mouse Click, get the input box populated/autofocused and Enter Key entered into it simultaneously/automatically instead of doing it manually. Will appreciated it the desired code is amended accordingly. thanks n sorry if not being so clear.


const trs = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
document.getElementById("search").onkeyup = e => {
  for (const tr of trs) tr.style.display = tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) ? "" : "none";
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 209px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  width: 100px;
}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <Meta charset="utf-8">
  <Meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</HEAD>

<TITLE>Equipments Details</TITLE>


<BODY style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px;">


  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">




  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Chairs and Pedals</td>
      <td>ہمارے پاس</td>
      <td>افلا</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tools plus Kits</td>
      <td>آج کے دن</td>
      <td>یجعلون</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tractors with Carts</td>
      <td>ٹریکٹرز بمعہ سامان</td>
      <td>اَلْھ</td>
    </tr>
  </table>



If I type manually the word  like Chairs or Tools in text box, the code works. Instead of typing manually, I wish to click any word from a TD of table , the input box may be populated and code executed accordingly. thanks

onkeyup is only fired when a key is released. Setting the value with mouse interaction will require something like the change event. MDN Change event

As presented you have kind of a sloppy mess of code with unclosed html elements etc. but your randomly place what appears to be JavaScript has document.getElementById("myTable") you your table does NOT have that id here.

`I have a table with ID 'myTable' and an input Box ID 'Search'. both those statements are incorrect here, you have neither id in your sample code.

"... I wish to paste it into input box with a mouse Click, get the input box populated/autofocused and Enter Key entered into it simultaneously/automatically instead of doing it manually." I don't see any code that shows that you've attempted to accomplish any of that. What code I do see was copied poorly.

You should listen to the input & change event instead of the keyup event. This approach ensures that the functionality works even when text is pasted from the clipboard, as shown below:


document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", filterRows);
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("change", filterRows);

function filterRows(e) {
    const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    for (const tr of trs) {
        tr.style.display = tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(query) ? "" : "none";
    }
}



To better capture additional fallback events, consider reviewing this answer. It provides a detailed description of the most important events you need to know. Check it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435525/5701662

Both functions are ok, but click function into TD is not there. If TD contains many words like "Tools and Kits", I wish to click only one word like "Tools" or "Kits" and get into input and get all rows containing this word. thanks.

For that particular wish my friend, you could select via document.querySeclector('#table td').addEleventListener("click", clickOption), good luck

Just add an event listener for the table and use the value of the clicked <td> to do the same thing that you are already doing with the search input.
Now when you click on a table entry, the table is redrawn without user interaction with the search input.
Note that your code was using a different id for the table in the HTML versus the JavaScript.


const table = document.getElementById("myTable")
const trs   = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
const search = document.getElementById("search")

table.addEventListener( "click", event =>  {
  if( event.target.tagName == "TD" ) {
    let data = event.target.innerText
    search.value = data
    limitTableEntries( data )
  }
} )

function limitTableEntries( data ) {
  for (const tr of trs)
  tr.style.display = tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(data.toLowerCase()) ? "" : "none";
}

document.getElementById("search").onkeyup = e => {
  limitTableEntries( e.target.value )
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 209px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  width: 100px;
}
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">

<!-- EDIT Changed id to match id used in js -->
<!-- <table id="table"> -->
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Chairs and  Pedals</td>
    <td>ہمارے پاس</td>
    <td>افلا</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tools plus Kits</td>
    <td>آج کے دن</td>
    <td>یجعلون</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tractors with Carts</td>
    <td>ٹریکٹرز بمعہ سامان</td>
    <td>اَلْھ</td>
  </tr>
</table>




On click code fetches total value in  a TD like "Tools plus Kits"  into input box, whereas I need  to click or double click only one desired word from these three words, like  either "Tools" or "plus" or "kits" to be copied in input box and get all data matching this word. will appreciated if code contains also copying from clipboard also. thanks
